# Active admin Resource redirect to new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have created a rails application and I have a product model.So when admin clicks on Product ,I need to open a page in new tab.Is it possible to open a page in new tab when admin clicks on resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Product"   do
  menu label: "Product", url: "#", html_options: { target: :blank }
end
```

Replace # with your url